# Question Marks Appear Instead of Spaces

Tags: c#, .net, character-encoding

I have a CSV file. When viewed in wordpad, there are spaces at the ends of some of the lines. When read via File.ReadAllText(filename) in C#, the spaces appear as ?. What could be causing this?

I'd like to eliminate this whitespace but using a regex doesn't work seeing as the question marks are mucking up the data.

Comment: What are you using to view the return value of `File.ReadAllText(filename)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could very well be that the characters displayed by Wordpad as spaces are in fact non-ASCII characters, or that the file is using an encoding that you do not expect in your C# program.

Have a look at the file in a hex editor.

If you don't have a hex editor handy, you can use [File.ReadAllBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes.aspx) to read in the file as a byte array and look for byte values that are outside the range of printable ASCII values near where you are seeing question marks.

Comment: The ASCII value is 160, which should be a non-breaking space, but is being displayed as a ?.

Comment: ASCII values only go up to 127 (in decimal).  Values of 128 and greater were traditionally referred to as Extended-ASCII.  Later, those values were used in various ways by various Unicode encoding standards.  The interpretation of the value 160 depends entirely on the character encoding in use.  160 (0xA0 in hex) is a NO-BREAK SPACE character in UTF-8 encoding.  If your viewer does not support UTF-8 encoding, it is not predictable what it will display without knowing more about it.  Some viewers display a ? or other character in such a situation.

Comment: Solution, it was in UTF7. I have never seen anyone send anything in UTF7. This was an excel file.... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> What could be causing this?

Unicode Letters.

Comment: How would I correctly eliminate this problem? Essentially, I'm simply removing whitespace, but the questionmarks are mucking up my data.

Answer (score 0):

What encoding are you using to reading the file with?

The default encoding (UTF-8) represents codepoints higher than 0x7F (127 decimal) as 2 or more octets. The codepoint 0xA0 (decimal 160) is encoded in UTF-8 as 0xC2A0.

When the decoder reads the octet 0xA0, that tells is that it is the lead-in octet of a codepoint encoded in two octots. The value you get is the codepoint represented by the encoding 0xA0?? where '??' is the value of the next octet in hex.

You need to read you file with the correct encoding. Not knowing the source of your file, it's hard to know. The most likely suspects, assuming a Windows environment, would be one of these encodings:

- The "standard" windows codepage, windows-1252
- ISO-8859-1 aka Latin-1
- ISO-8859-2 aka Latin-2

You can get an instance thusly:

```
Encoding windows1252 = Encoding.GetEncoding( "windows-1252" ) ;
Encoding latin1      = Encoding.GetEncoding( "iso-8859-1"   ) ;
Encoding latin2      = Encoding.GetEncoding( "iso-8859-2"   ) ;
```

Usage is something like:

```
    Encoding windows1252Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding( "windows-1252" ) ;

    using ( TextReader tr = new StreamReader( @"c:\foo\bar\bazbat.csz" , windows1252Encoding ) )
    {
        string line ;
        while ( null != (line=tr.ReadLine()) )
        {
            process( line ) ;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a old post, but sharing my fix so it may be useful to some one.

I was getting a similar issue.When the .CSV file was posted, i was suppose to read the file and extract the content.

While doing so all the white space characters were getting converted in to �����

var contentAsString = Encoding.UTF7
                    .GetString(contentAsByteArray, 0, contentAsByteArray.Length - 1);

Adding the proper encoding type, fixed my issue.

first i am reading the file as Byte Array and then applying the encoding type.